# Running web application components as a single service versus multiple services in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, kompose

I have a web applicaton (e.g. `"india"`) that depends on postgres and redis (e.g. a typical Rails application).

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that composes the containers to start this application.

```
version: '3'
services:

  redis-india:
    image: redis:5.0.6-alpine
    # .....

  postgres-india:
    image: postgres:11.5-alpine
    # ....

  india:
    depends_on:
      - postgres-india
      - redis-india
    image: india/india:local
    # ....
```

I'd like to run this application deployment with Kubernetes. I'm trying to figure out how to build the k8s resource objects correctly, and I'm weighing two options:

1. I can build `india`, `postgres-india`, and `redis-india` as separate deployments (and therefore separate Services) in k8s
2. I can build `india`, `postgres-india`, and `redis-india` as a single deployment (and therfore a single `pod` / `service`)

#2 makes more sense to me personally - all 3 items here comprise the entire "application service" that should be exposed as a single service URL (i.e. the frontend for the web application).

However, if I use an [automated tool like `kompose`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/translate-compose-kubernetes/) to translate my `docker-compose.yml` file into k8s resources, it follows approach #1 and creates three individual k8s Services.

Is there a "right way" or standard I should follow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Independent components

Your three components should run as separate deployments on Kubernetes. You want these three components to be:

- Independently upgradable and deployable (e.g. you deploy a new version of Redis but not your app or database)
- Independently scalable - e.g. you might get many users and want to scale up to multiple instances (e.g. 5 replicas) of your app.

#### State

Your app should be designed to be [stateless](https://12factor.net/processes), and can be deployed as a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/). But the Redis and PostgreSQL are *stateful* components and should be deployed as [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/).

#### Availability

In a production environment, you typically want to:

- Avoid downtime when upgrading any application or database
- Avoid downtime if you or the cloud provider upgrade the node
- Avoid downtime if the node crash, e.g. due to hardware failure or kernel crash.

With a *stateless* app deployed as a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), this is trivial to solve - run at least two instances (replicas) of it - and make sure they are deployed on different nodes in the cluster. You can do this using [Topology Spread Constraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/).

With a *stateful* component as e.g. Redis or PostgreSQL, this is more difficult. You typically need to run it as a cluster. See e.g. [Redis Cluster](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial). But it is more difficult for PostgreSQL, you could consider a PostgreSQL-compatible db that has a distributed design, e.g. [CockroachDB](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/product/sql/) that is designed to be [run on Kubernetes](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/deploy-cockroachdb-with-kubernetes.html) or perhaps consider [CrunchyData PostgreSQL Operator](https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgres-operator/v5/).

## Pod with multiple containers

When you deploy a Pod with [multiple containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#how-pods-manage-multiple-containers), one container is the "main" application and the other containers are supposed to be "helper" / "utility" containers to fix a problem for the "main container" - e.g. if your app logs to two different files - you could have helper containers to tail those files and output it to stdout, as is the recommended log output in [Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/logs). You typically only use "multiple containers" for apps that are not designed to be run on Kubernetes, or if you want to extend with some functionality like e.g. a Service Mesh.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! So all 3 components in my mind make up an "application environment" (they're all required pieces for this web app to run). Put another way, an "environment" is a collection of deployments. Does k8s provide a resource to model that or is "deployment" the highest conceptual resource there is?

Comment: You could have a `namespace` for that "environment". See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/